# Rotation + Translation of vectors

Tags: matrices, geometry, transformation, rotations

I have two sets of three intersecting orthogonal vectors, with direction vectors: $\vec{X}$, $\vec{Y}$, and $\vec{Z}$. Each set has a different intersection point (point $A$ and point $B$). Also, none of the vectors are parallel to another.
If I know all the direction vectors and intersection points coordinates, how do I translate and rotate one set to another (say, $A$ to $B$)? In other words, what is the function $\,f(\cdot)$ for this transformation?

[image]

Comment: Hint: the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the transformation from $A$ to $B$ the best  method to describe it, is to use homogeneous notation.
You can write a position and orientation of the frame $A$ in a base $0$ frame as
${^0}H_A= \begin{bmatrix}
\vec{X_A} & \vec{Y_A} & \vec{Z_A} & \vec{A_A} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ where 
$A_A= \begin{bmatrix}
{A_x}   \\
{A_y}   \\
{A_z}   
 \end{bmatrix}$,

and frame B in the same base frame as

${^0}H_B = \begin{bmatrix}
\vec{X_A} & \vec{Y_B} & \vec{Z_B} & \vec{B_B} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ where 
$B_B= \begin{bmatrix}
{B_x}   \\
{B_y}   \\
{B_z}   
 \end{bmatrix}$.

Now you have transition from $0$ to $A$ and from $A$ to $B$  denoted as ${^0}H_A{^A}H_B={^0}H_B$ and then ${^A}H_B=({^0}H_A^{-1}){^0}H_B$ what gives the wanted solution.

Comment: Ah, I never thought the solution could be this simple. I didn't consider inverting the transformation matrix. I tested this method with some point coordinates and compared the results with the [Horn's method](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26186-absolute-orientation-horn-s-method?). The values are similar up to 11 decimal places so this method should be correct. Of course, your method gives more accurate results since it uses the absolute transformation matrix.

Comment: @UmarZain The method of homogeneous notation of position and orientation is widely used in robotics and computer vision. It's worth to use it because it gives the answer only with matrix multiplication and finding an inverse if needed.. I hope it is suitable also for your problem..

Comment: @UmarZain to add some concluding remark the homogeneous notation is convenient  because assures that products of multiplication of such matrices and inverses are also in this form i.e. the last row of the matrix is [0,0,0,1] - 0's are linked with columns representing orientation and 1 with the column representing position of frame origin.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26186-absolute-orientation-horn-s-method?
The algorithm in this website gives me the transformation matrix for this question. The matrix is just an estimate but I believe this method would be useful for problems that are more complex than this question.